# MVVM Light Commands within an DataTemplate

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I created a User Control which contains a ListView. I want to add a RelayCommand when the user change the text of a nested TextBox (using MVVM Light) :

```
<UserControl xmlns:my="clr-namespace:UI.View"  x:Class="UI.View.MontureView"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Monture}" Margin="0,39,0,95" Height="600" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Qte" Width="50" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Qte}" Width="40" TextAlignment="Right" Name="a">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged" >
                                            <cmd:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding MontureViewModel.MyProperty}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=a}" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

In my VM I have : (I removed some parts of the code)

```
namespace UI.ViewModel
{
    public class MontureViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MontureViewModel()
        {
            MyProperty = new RelayCommand<TextBox>(e =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
            });
        }
        public RelayCommand<TextBox> MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tryied to add an event on a TextBox which isn't nested into a DataTemplate (outside of the ListView) and it works.
I think that I have to modify the code when I'm into the DataTemplate.

Any idea ?

Comment: do you have any binding error in the debug output window? please check it

Comment: I have Nothing error in the debug output windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=a}" to

CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=a}".  This binds the CommandParameter to the selected Item of the GridView and the ElementName sets the control it is bound to within the binding.